# Why isn't Vader in the Super Star Destroyer Executor at the beginning of Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi

Why didn't Vader arrive at the second Death Star in the Super Star Destroyer *Executor* instead of some smaller Star Destroyer when meeting with Moff Jerjerrod?

Is there any Legends or canon explanation for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vader arrives on a bog-standard Star Destroyer **because the Emperor is using *The Executor* as his own command ship**. He arrives on it a few days later, presumably having taken time out to visit a spa, do some tourist things and just generally chillax before getting down to the nitty-gritty of inspiring abject terror in his Death Star workforce.

> The Super Star Destroyer rested in space above the half-completed
>   Death Star battle station and its green neighbor, Endor. The Destroyer
>   was a massive ship, attended by numerous smaller warships of various
>   kinds, which hovered or darted around the great mother ship like
>   children of different ages and temperaments: medium range fleet
>   cruisers, bulky cargo vessels, TIE fighter escorts.
>
> ...
>
> When he entered the docking bay, thousands of Imperial troops snapped
>   to attention with a momentous clap. The shuttle came to rest on the
>   pod. Its ramp lowered like a dragon’s jaw, and the Emperor’s royal
>   guard ran down, red robes flapping, as if they were licks of flame
>   shooting out of the mouth to herald the angry roar. They poised
>   themselves at watchful guard in two lethal rows beside the ramp.
>   Silence filled the great hall. At the top of the ramp, the Emperor
>   appeared.
>
> <sub><sup>[Return of the Jedi: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(novel))</sup></sub>

Pablo Hidalgo of the Lucasfilm Story Group has [confirmed](https://twitter.com/OrigamiYoda/status/651441665950007296) that there was only one Super Star Destroyer present at the Battle of Endor (that being *The Executor*).

[image]

This is also confirmed in the (canon) short story [*The Levers of Power*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Levers_of_Power) in which a battlefield display shows the ships in orbit of Endor to include *The Executor*.

> Sloane could see the arrowheads of other Star Destroyers to either
>   side of her, and farther down the line the shining bulk of the
>   Executor, the massive dreadnought that served as flagship of the task
>   force.

That being said, a couple of more recent novels (including the [new Junior novelisation of RotJ](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!) and [Aftermath: Life Debt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Life_Debt) both identify the Emperor's arriving ship as the *Eclipse*. No explanation is given for this canon discrepancy.